# Passing messages in message Queue

Tags: message-queue

How can I, in my application, sent a message as input to my application using message queue?
It is showing as number of messages in message queue is zero.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What message queue? What language? What environment?

Comment: The one which we will get from Messaging Queuing which will be there in computer management and it will act as input to my application. But there when i will add values it is taking as zero messages in message queue.

Comment: Are you talking about MSMQ on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you use Linux and C language, a simple example how POSIX message queue can be used to pass data between separate threads or processes can be found [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0XUbhIBbEc&ab_channel=AR-Embedded).